# Prove $H\cap K$ Abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a group with $|H|=24$ and $|K|=20$. Prove that $H\cap K$ Abelian.

I am unsure where to start with this proof. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of both $H$ and $K$, therefore its order must...

Comment: its order must divide $|HK|$?? or both $|H|$ and $|K|$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$H\cap K$ is a group being the intersection of two groups. Also it is a subgroup of both, so its order must divide both $20$ and $24$, hence the order of $H\cap K$ can be atmost $4$. Let $x$ and $y$ be two elements of $H\cap K$. If $x$ and $y$ doesn't commute then show that $e,x,y,xy,yx$ are $5$ distinct elements of $H\cap K$, which leads to a contradiction. So any group having order $\leq 4$ must be abelian.

Comment: Just to add that, if we can assume the OP already knows that all groups of order 1, 2 and 4 are Abelian, the proof gets even simpler.

Comment: Yes, this is quite trivial. We showed this our first course in group theory.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $H\cap K$ subgroup  for subgroups $H$ and $K$.Therefore,

$|H\cap K|$ could be $1, 2, 4$ by Lagrance Theorem. We know also that if $G$ is a group with $|G|\leq 5$, then $G$ is abealian. In particular,

$\textbf{ Case 1)}$  If $|H\cap K|=1$, then $H\cap K=\{1\}$.

$\textbf{ Case 2)}$ if  $|H\cap K|=2$, then we know that every prime order is cyclic and every cyclic group is abelian.

$\textbf{ Case 3)}$ If $|H\cap K|=4$, then it is isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z_4}$ or $4$-group $V$ which are abelian.